# How do I change the footer/footline of a single frame in Beamer?

Tags: latex, frame, footer, beamer

So basically I've got something like this at the top of my tex file:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{Number \insertframenumber}
```

This applies "Number <#>" to the footer/footline of all frames.  Now what I want to do is change the footline for **one single frame**.  Surprisingly, the following doesn't work:

```
\begin{frame}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{New template \insertframenumber}
\end{frame}
```

How do I achieve changing the footline/footer for **one single frame**?

Comment: Maybe if you put the template-changing command *before* the `\begin{frame}`? You'd have to change it back afterwards, or maybe it works if you put the entire thing between `{` and `}`. If not, leave a comment and I'll start experimenting.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Thanks Thomas! For anyone else who might want to get this working, here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{goo \insertframenumber}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Frame 1}
        A
    \end{frame}

    { % these braces make the change local to the single frame
        \setbeamertemplate{footline}{boo \insertframenumber}
        \begin{frame}[t]{Frame 2}
            B
        \end{frame}
    }

    \begin{frame}[t]{Frame 3}
        C
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Jrop, mark it as resolved (tick below answer's reputation number) and vote up Thomas's comment (orange arrow that will appear on left side of the comment).